# Google Tag Manager not Working?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set up some tags using Google Tag Manager to track click event. I went in to check event states on Google Analytics(GA). I couldn't see any event on GA. And I try to send event just by GA directly. It's work. I'm sure GTM it's work before. But now I don't know what happen? I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!

### My Environment

Mobile : iPhone 8

iOS Version : 11.2

XCode Version : 9.2

Google Library : GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.17

(*) I also tried it on Android. It's not work too.

### My GA Code

[image: This is my GA code.]

Some GA event log are showed on terminal.
[image: Some GA event log are showed on terminal.]

I could see record on GA console.
[image: I could see record on GA console.]

This is my GTM code.
[image: This is my GTM code.]

Some GTM event log are showed on terminal.
[image: Some GTM event log are showed on terminal.]

The GTM event log are not display on console.
[image: The GTM event log are not display on console.]

### Research

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Google-Tag-Manager-Stopped-Working/td-p/1249146

https://github.com/kraihn/cordova-plugin-tag-manager/issues/34

Comment: Have you assigned custom dimensions to each event? You have to create custom dimensions in your analytics and tag them in the GTM when the event gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, #Sathishkumar Jayaraj.

It's work. I followed your idea creating custom dimensions and tag them in GTM. But when I recover my project setting. It's still work. It's confused me.

### My Setting

Push data structure
[image]

GTM setting
[image]

Triggering
[image]

Event
[image]

-

Now I get the event. But it show key-info apparently. I will try to show value-info.